# can we do the same thing without using telerik controls and just using MVC3 and c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

can this be done with mvc3 and c# with out using telerik controls.

`@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("yearComboBox")
            .DropDownHtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px; white-space:nowrap;" })
            .Items(item =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
                {
                    item.Add().Text((DateTime.Now.Year -    i).ToString()).Value((DateTime.Now.Year - i).ToString());
                }
            })
        )`

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot achieve that with only ASP.NET MVC 3 and C#. You will have to use javascript and probably CSS (if you want to make it pretty) in order to create an autocomplete dropdownlist. You may take a look at [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which could simplify the *javascript part*.

Comment: the logic which i used with telerik can it be doen in mvc3 in the view

Comment: @Findings, sure, don't forget the javascript part. Without it, this logic won't work.